# Returning a single property from a LINQ query result

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

The following expression returns a contact - the whole contact with dozens of properties. This is fine but, ideally, I'd like the return to be the contact's id (contact.contactId) property only. How do I do this?

```
var assocOrg = Contacts.Where(x => x.ContactTypeID == 2 && x.OrganizationName == "COMPANY XYZ");
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
var result = Contacts.Where(x => ...)
                     .Select(x => x.ContactID);
```

or

```
var result = from x in Contacts
             where x.ContactTypeID == 2 && x.OrganizationName == "COMPANY XYZ"
             select x.ContactID;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get a single or first object matching your conditions , use this :

```
  var result = Contacts.Where(x => ...)
   .Select(x => x.ContactID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var assocOrg = Contacts.
               Where(x => x.ContactTypeID == 2 && x.OrganizationName == "COMPANY XYZ").
               Select(x => x.contactId);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var assocOrg = Contacts.Where(x => x.ContactTypeID == 2 && x.OrganizationName == "COMPANY XYZ").Select(x=> x.contactId).FirstOrDefault();
```

That would get you the first ContactId and the following would get you a list of ContactId's

```
var assocOrg = Contacts.Where(x => x.ContactTypeID == 2 && x.OrganizationName == "COMPANY XYZ").Select(x=> x.contactId);
```

In Sql style that would be

```
var assocOrg = from contact in Contacts
               where contact.ContactTypeId == 2 && contact.OrganizationName == "COMPANY XYZ"
               select contact.ContactId;
```

Comment: Your're right, should be fixed and I'm putting it into VS now to test it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = Contacts.Where(x => ...)
           .Select(x => x.ContactID).FirstOrDefault();
```