# Limiting fields returned in a LINQ query

Tags: linq, .net-4.0

A few days ago I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287789/returning-a-single-property-from-a-linq-query-result) about returning select fields from a LINQ query. Now, I want to add some grouping to the results and things are not working out.

The following query returns the correct rows but I want to limit the fields returned. For example, I only want to see the Id and Name fields.

```
var contactsFromDealers = Contacts.Where(x => x.ContactTypeID == 2).GroupBy (x => x.OrganizationName)
```

and appending `.Select (x => x.Id, x.OrganizationName)` doesn't help.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try .Select( x => new { x.Name } )

Answer (score 3):

you need the select before the group by i believe.