# How to select only one column to return an object in linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to select only CourseId property but it gives me an error

```
  Course co = db.Courses.Include("Students").Where(c => c.CourseName == "C#")
            .Select(cc => new Course() { CourseId = cc.CourseId }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Error:

An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The entity or complex type 'Database1Model.Course' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: So you only wand `CourseId` and the associated students?

Comment: If you just want IDs, you can drop the .Include("Students") part.  Also, you are selecting a new object that is an int and trying to assign to the type Course.  You might want to use var: var courseIds = db.Courses.Where(c => c.CourseName == "C#")
            .Select(cc => new Course() { CourseId = cc.CourseId });

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning a single property from a LINQ query result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287789/returning-a-single-property-from-a-linq-query-result) -- depending on your response to @juharr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity framework does not allow you to construct an entity type in a LINQ-to-SQL query.

You can instead, just select `cc.CourseId` on the SQL side, and then construct the `Course` entity after the execution of the SQL query like this:

```
var id = db.Courses
             .Include("Students")
             .Where(c => c.CourseName == "C#")
             .Select(cc => cc.CourseId)
             .SingleOrDefault();

var course = new Course() { CourseId = id  };
```

By the way, why are you including "Students" if you just need the course id?

Comment: Doesn't this lose the `Students` then.

Comment: @juharr, OP doesn't seem to want to include them in the output object. This seems confusing. I ask about this at the end of my answer.

Comment: Since they want a `Course` object it would include the `Students` collection.  I'm just not sure why they wouldn't want the rest of the `Course` columns in that case unless there are a lot.  It's a bit unclear right now.

Comment: @YacoubMassad  Thank you for your help :) I just wanted to get an OBJECT of type Course with their students with only one trip to database 

Why CourseId ? it can be CourseName also

Answer (score 3):

What about this

```
var courseAndStudents = db.Courses
    .Where(c => c.CourseName == "C#")
    .Select(cc => new { cc.CourseId, cc.Students })
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

You'll only get the `CourseId` and all the `Students`.

Or if you don't really need the `Students` then just select the `CourseId`

```
var courseId = db.Courses
    .Where(c => c.CourseName == "C#")
    .Select(cc => cc.CourseId)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I just wanted to get an OBJECT of type Course with their students with
>   only one trip to database

If that's the case, then modify Yacoub's answer:

UPDATE:

```
var sourceWithStudents = db.Courses
                           .Include("Students")
                           .Where(c => c.CourseName == "C#")
                           .Select(c => new Course() { CourseName = c.CourseName, Students = c.Students} )
                           .SingleOrDefault();
```

`sourceWithStudents` will contain a `Course` object populated with `Students`.

This should get what you're after. I would question your model. If you truly only need the name and students, you should be selecting a Course class that only contains those two things.

Comment: Thank you Spivonious  :) what about if i need the object with students and course name only Course co = db.Courses.Include("Students").Where(c => c.CourseName == "C#") .Select(cc => new Course() { CourseName  = cc.CourseName }).SingleOrDefault();

Comment: See my edit. I do wonder if your model could use some re-design though.

Comment: Thank you for your help ... it's not working it gives the same error